# is it possible to forbid assignment if there is no explicit copy constructor? c++

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

Let's assume I have class with no explicit copy constructor. Is it possible to forbid operation of assigning or copying objects for this class? For example:

```
class A
{
   // data, methods, but no copy constructor and no overloaded assignment operator
};

A object1;
A object2;

object1 = object2; // make compiler error here

A object3 = object1; // or here
```

Comment: What do you mean by "class with no explicit copy constructor."? Do you mean the class in not copy constructable, or that you didn't define a copy constructor?

Comment: I didn't define one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could mark the copy-constructor and copy-assignment operator as deleted:

```
class A
{
public:
    ...

    A(const A&) = delete;
    A& operator=(const A&) = delete;
};
```

If your compiler doesn't support C++11 features like this, just make the functions `private`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
private:

        A(A const&); //Don't implement it
        A& operator=(A const&);//Don't implement it
```

or with C++ 11

```
        A(A const&)             = delete;
        A& operator=(A const&)  = delete;
```

Answer (score 1):

> Let's assume I have class with no explicit copy constructor. Is it possible to forbid operation of assigning or copying objects for this class?

Derive it from `boost::noncopyable`, a base class that is non-copyable, or add a non-static data member that is non-copyable.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont have explicit copy constructor. compiler will create a default one for you.

- To forbid copying make copy constructor private.
- To forbid assignment make assignment operator private

Answer (score 0):

I also can declare copy constructor or assignment operator without definition. When I call either of them I get linker error.

Answer (score 0):

The implicit copy constructor and assignment operator can only be called if the compiler can generate them. They (conceptually, at least) copy the base class, and then perform memberwise copy of all members.  If either of those operations cannot be performed, no implicit copy constructor or assignment operator is generated.

Therefore, you can inhibit these operations by deriving from a non-copyable base class or by including a (non-static) member of a non-copyable type.

As a coding principle, I think it's clearer to explicitly declare the operations as deleted (or private, pre-C++11) members, rather than relying on the presence of a non-copyable member or base class.  I'll make an exception if the member/base is named to convey that intent (e.g. `boost::noncopyable`).

Answer (score 0):

Your question has two part:

First is Explicit constructor, the purpose of explicit constructor is to avoid the implicit construction. By implicit construction I mean

```
struct C {
    int a;
    C(int p):a(p) {}
    ~C(){std::cout<<"Destructor for "<<a<<'\n';}
};
int main() {
  C c1 = 142; // implicit-initialization, calls C::C(42)
  C c2{12}; // 

  return 0;
}
```

But if we make constructor explicit as

```
explicit C(int a);
```

Then following code will not compile.

```
C c1 = 142; // would not compile
```

This was about the explicit constructor.

Second part is avoiding copy and assignment. So, for that you have two options

1. As suggested by others,use boost::noncopyable
2. Remember "The rule of three/five/zero"
       http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three, make your
       copy ctor, move ctor & assignment operator as deleted.